# Qt-Frameless window and OS button

Tags: c++, c, qt, interface

**Hello,**

I have a frameless application in which i have reimplemented my menu bar. I want to get the default close, minimize and maximize button for the os (Max, Windows ...).

Can somebody give me a sort of guideline or tips to do so ? I've tried using :

`maxPix = style()->standardPixmap(QStyle::SP_TitleBarMaxButton);` but i can't find the corresponding one.

Thank you deeply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try playing around with **CustomizeWindowHint** and setting Qt::WindowMinimizeButtonHint after you set Qt::FramelessWindowHint.

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qt.html

Search for CustomizeWindowHint flag.